# Why arent titles and locations displaying in my .ics file?

Tags: icalendar

I am building an .ics file in my web app that emails clients with events.

The ics contents is as follows:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:a0F8E00000oRFD1UAO
DTSTART:20200409T100000
DTEND:20200409T110000
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:DISPLAY
SUMMARY:VNI-073
LOCATION:Location 1, Tower Hill, , United Kingdom
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:a0F8E00000oRFD2UAO
DTSTART:20200409T113000
DTEND:20200409T123000
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:DISPLAY
SUMMARY:VNI-074
LOCATION: Location 2, Buckingham Place, SW1E, United Kingdom
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:a0F8E00000oRFD3UAO
DTSTART:20200409T130000
DTEND:20200409T140000
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:DISPLAY
SUMMARY:VNI-075
LOCATION:Location 3, 170 Piccadilly, W1J 9EU, United Kingdom
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The title of the event and the location are not added to my calendar entry (see screenshot):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your summary and location properties are embedded in the VALARM component (i.e. between the BEGIN:VALARM and END:VALARM) instead of being properties at the VEVENT level

Concretely, instead of

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:a0F8E00000oRFD1UAO
DTSTART:20200409T100000
DTEND:20200409T110000
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:DISPLAY
SUMMARY:VNI-073
LOCATION:Location 1, Tower Hill, , United Kingdom
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```

you want to do

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:a0F8E00000oRFD1UAO
DTSTART:20200409T100000
DTEND:20200409T110000
SUMMARY:VNI-073
LOCATION:Location 1, Tower Hill, , United Kingdom
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```